# Detecte login faild on facebook iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm using facebook SDK v4.12.0 in my iOS app. I want to detect if the user failed to login, how can I achieve this ?

This is my code

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
            [loginManager logOut];
            [loginManager setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];

            [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_friends"]
                                fromViewController:self
                                           handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
......
}];
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add `public_profile` permissions as well.

Comment: thank you but I'm trying to figure out my problem now

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my project:

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"FB auth error %@", [error detailedInfo]);

   // User in NOT logged in

   // Handle FB error here
}
else if (result.isCancelled) {
    NSLog(@"FB auth cancelled");
    [loginManager logOut];

   // User in NOT logged in        
}
else {

    // check if specific permissions missing
    if (![result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
        NSLog(@"\"email\" FB permissions are missing");
    }
    // ...add more granted permissions check when needed

    NSLog(@"FB auth succeeded");

    // User in logged in

    // login user with you server if required
}
```

Comment: I need to know if the user while trying to login failed.

Comment: The login is failed when an error is returned OR the login attempt is cancelled.

Comment: I think these are not only the cases because if the password or user name is wrong this also a failed login. Thanks @Eugene

Comment: This kind of errors are handled by Facebook. While attempting to log in with incorrect email/password, the user either will log in successfully or cancel the attempt. Both results are delivered to your application via the callback.

Comment: So you say I can't detect Failed login ?

Comment: Facebook in this case, works as a "facade". It handles these errors internally by presenting error messages to the user. The callback is called when something, which requires actions from the app is needed. While there are error like "wrong password" your code can do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2, use the `LoginButtonDelegate` method:

```
func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {

    switch result{
    case .cancelled:
        print("user cancelled login through facebook")

    case .failed(let error):
     print("user couldn't log in due to error \(error.localizedDescription)")

    case .success( _, _, _):
         print("user logged in successfully")
    }

    print("result is \(result)")

}
```